#  Put class error when I use validate

Tags: 7

I am working with the Metatags module, and I have these fields.

[image]

I need that looks like as in the following screenshot, when the fields meta description and meta keywords are validated.

[image]

This is my code, I don't know how can include the class error and put the * symbol.  My question is related with styles.  I want the field keywords and description looks as fields required for the user.

```
mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form_id = $form['form_id']['#value'];
  if ($form_id == "article_node_form") {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_test_validation';
  }
}

function mymodule_test_validation($form, &$form_state) {
   if (($form_state['values']['metatags']['description']['value'] == '')) {
        form_set_error('Description', t('field is required'));
      } 
      if (($form_state['values']['metatags']['keywords']['value'] == '')) {
        form_set_error('Keywords', t('field is required'));     
      }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what is not working? Is it that the text isn't red and therefore a styling issue? Is it that the fields are never validated as you want them to be? Are you sure your field names are with the first character capitalized?

Comment: If a field description or keywords is empty appears the error message, it's doing the validation,  I need the styles, the field is in red when the fields are empty and put the * symbol in the label Keyword and Description.   Thanks very much.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand what you want and what's happening. Can you update your question with *the html markup as it is now* and also *the markup of how you want it to be*?

Comment: I have updated my question.  Excuse me for my poor english.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okey, I understand your issue now. At this date (correct me if I'm wrong) Drupal doesn't print the error messages at the side of every single field. Instead, they are printed in a html unsorted list in `page.tpl.php` with the variable `$messages` (search for `print $messages;` or add it yourself in that template file). A quick search found me an answer [here](http://drupal.org/node/318978#comment-1521230) which could probably be modified for your needs. [Here is the issue at Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1493324).

Answer (score -1):

If the only validation you are looking for is to make sure the fields are required, then you don't need to call to a validation function. The solution in that case will be to set the "required" attribute to TRUE for the fields description and keywords in the "form_alter" function. This solution will give you the style you are looking for in the required fields.

Something like this (this is a proof of concept):

```
mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form_id = $form['form_id']['#value'];
  if ($form_id == "article_node_form") {
    // Make META DESCRIPTION required
    $form['metatags']['description'] = array('#require' => TRUE,);

    // Make META KEYWORDS required
    $form['metatags']['keywords'] = array('#require' => TRUE,);
  }
}
```

To get the right field names do the following:

```
mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form_id = $form['form_id']['#value'];
  if ($form_id == "article_node_form") {

   print_r($form);

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tested the option and this code is not working for me.  With this code the tab metatags disappears and if I put $form['#metatags']['metatags']['description'] = array('#require' => TRUE,); appears the tab but are not validated the fields.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi I used the $form['#metatags']['metatags']['description'] as a proof of concept, I have no idea what is the field name. A solution to get the right field name inside the "if ($form_id == "article_node_form")" add print_r($form); to get the right field name.

Comment: Thanks.  I asked in the support of the module metatags, I think is useful in this forum put this thread:  http://drupal.org/node/1782830#comment-6478322